# Will the form get submitted twice if I use onclick handler to submit the form in javascript function

Tags: javascript, html

I am confused by the following code. Will the form get submitted twice when a user click the form button?

```
<html>
  <body>
  <script type="text/javascript">
    function formSubmit() {
      document.getElementById("myForm").submit()
    }
  </script>

  <form id="myForm" action="js_form_action.asp" method="get">
   Firstname: <input type="text" name="myname" size="20"><br />
   <input type="submit" onclick="formSubmit()" value="please submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

So the js function "formSubmit()" (triggeded by onclick eventhandler) will submit the form once.

And then since "preventDefault" is not used in the js function, the default action (trigged by the form onsubmit event) will submit the form again. So the form is submitted twice. Am I correct?

Comment: No it won't, but it makes no sense to use the submit handler in javascript unless you prevent the default submit and actually do something. Just calling `form.submit()` does exactly the same as not calling it, or it would have, had you used a proper submit button !

Comment: A `"button"` input doesn't submit the form IIRC. Only a `"submit"` input type. So I doubt that the form would be submitted twice.

Comment: You should add the function to the `submit` event of the form, and prevent the default behavior with `preventDefault`

Comment: adeneo, thanks, I corrected the typo in the above code (now I am using a proper submit button).  But I do not understand, why the form did not get submitted twice?  In formSubmit(), I intentionally did not use preventDefault. So the default action will submit the form again, right?

Comment: @BrandonBuck I agree, `<input type="submit">` will submit the form. If you have onClick event it will be triggered too, but after the submit, page refreshes, so the onClick event is some cases can't complete. But I think some old browsers submits the form even if `<button type="submit">` is pressed.